# Query about CI's DB function '$query->row_array()'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the DB class of CI framework. There're 5 rows queried out from the first line, and the second line printed 5, but why did the statement `count($query->row_array())`(or `count($query->row_array(),1)`) returned 11(the field number of table) and only one row filled in the result, rather than 5 rows?

```
$query = $this->db->query($SQL_BYLABEL, array($labelId, $orderby, (int)$m, (int)$n));
    log_message('error', $query->num_rows());  // 5 rows
    log_message('error', count($query->row_array()));  // 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$query->row_array()` returns the data of one record as an array. So `count($query->row_array()` return the number of columns of the table.

***[Check the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)***.